# Spring data jdbc seems not working with final attributes

Tags: java, spring-data-jdbc

I'm trying spring data JDBC (1.1.0.M3). I have a Formateur (Teacher) class which contains an email attribute (class Email). Email is an immutable class. When I retrieve all the teachers from the database, I have the following

> exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot set
>   immutable property fr.yestech.data.jdbc.domain.Email.email

It seems that spring data JDBC doesn't work well with final attributes!

```
public class Formateur {

    private @Id Long id;
    private String nom;
    @Embedded
    private Email email;

...
}
```

Email class (Immutable class so no setters !)

```
public final class Email {

    private final String email;
    private static final Pattern EMAIL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^[_A-Za-z]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");

    private Email(String email) {
      Objects.requireNonNull(email, "Adresse email doit être non null!");
        if (!EMAIL_PATTERN.matcher(email).matches())
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("L'adresse email est 
                     invalide !");
        this.email = email;
    }

    public static Email of(String email) {
        return new Email(email);
    }
...
}
```

Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringJdbcApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringJdbcApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner applicationRunner(FormateurRepository formateurRepository) {
        return args -> {
            Formateur teacher = Formateur.of("YesTech", Email.of("yestech@email.com"), Adresse.of("Goux"));

            formateurRepository.save(teacher); 
            formateurRepository.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bug. 
You can work around it by adding a "wither"

```
private Email withEmail(String email) {
    return new withEmail(email);
}
```

It may even be private.

I created [an issue for this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-370), so it gets fixed soonish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer was helpful please upvote it. If it solved your problem accept it.